# iOS Core Animation: CALayer bringSublayerToFront?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, calayer

How do I bring a `CALayer sublayer` to the front of all sublayers, analogous to `-[UIView bringSubviewToFront]`?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I don't think such methods exist, but it's easy to roll your own.

```
// CALayer+Additions.h

@interface CALayer (Additions)
- (void)bringSublayerToFront:(CALayer *)layer;
- (void)sendSublayerToBack:(CALayer *)layer;
@end

// CALayer+Additions.m

@implementation CALayer (Additions)

- (void)bringSublayerToFront:(CALayer *)layer {
    CALayer *superlayer = self.superlayer;
    [self removeFromSuperlayer];
    [superlayer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:[self.sublayers count]-1];
}

- (void)sendSublayerToBack:(CALayer *)layer {
    CALayer *superlayer = self.superlayer;
    [self removeFromSuperlayer];
    [superlayer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Any chance to get an explanation why someone has downvoted this?

Comment: Probably because the code is wrong. The argument layer is not used. gradientLayer is not defined. The superlayer call is not needed because the layer argument's superlayer is self. ivanzoid has posted corrected code.

Answer (score 58):

I'm curious why none of these answers mention the zPosition attribute on CALayer.  Core Animation looks at this attribute to figure out layer rendering order.  The higher the value, the closer it is to the front.  These answers all work as long as your zPosition is 0, but to easily bring a layer to the front, set its zPosition value higher than all other sublayers.

Comment: I totally forgot about zPosition and this answer is the best. Both answers work but this one is more simplistic and reliable IMO

Comment: From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/BuildingaLayerHierarchy/BuildingaLayerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH6-SW4): "When inserting above or below another sublayer, you are only specifying the sublayer’s position in the sublayers array. The actual visibility of the layers is determined primarily by the value in their zPosition property and secondarily by their position in the sublayers array."

Comment: Except changing the zPosition isn't working for me for some reason. I'm trying to draw it on top of the TabBarController's TabBar and can't figure out why it won't bring it (draw) in front of it.

Answer (score 44):

This is variation of @MattDiPasquale's implementation which reflects UIView's logic more precisely:

```
- (void) bringSublayerToFront:(CALayer *)layer
{
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [self insertSublayer:layer atIndex:[self.sublayers count]];
}

- (void) sendSublayerToBack:(CALayer *)layer
{
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [self insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
}
```

**Note**: if you don't use ARC, you may wish to add `[layer retain]` at top and `[layer release]` at bottom of both functions to make sure `layer` is not accidentally destructed in a case it has retain count = 1.

Comment: the `removeFromSuperlayer` methods are unnecessary as it will be removed automatically when calling `insertSublayer`.

Comment: Another problem with the removeFromSuperlayer: if layer is the only sublayer, removing it apparently causes the sublayers array to nil out. In Swift, this leads to an option-unwrapping crash on self.sublayers. (It may be OK on Obj-C, as [nil count] probably returns 0, which actually works).

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4 version.
Idea that layer itself has `bringToFront` and `sendToBack` methods.

```
#if os(iOS)
   import UIKit
#elseif os(OSX)
   import AppKit
#endif

extension CALayer {

   func bringToFront() {
      guard let sLayer = superlayer else {
         return
      }
      removeFromSuperlayer()
      sLayer.insertSublayer(self, at: UInt32(sLayer.sublayers?.count ?? 0))
   }

   func sendToBack() {
      guard let sLayer = superlayer else {
         return
      }
      removeFromSuperlayer()
      sLayer.insertSublayer(self, at: 0)
   }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let view = NSView(frame: ...)
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor

let l1 = CALayer(...)
let l2 = CALayer(...)

view.layer?.addSublayer(l1)
view.layer?.addSublayer(l2)

l1.bringToFront()
```

Answer (score 8):

Right code here

```
- (void)bringSublayerToFront:(CALayer *)layer {
    CALayer *superlayer = layer.superlayer;
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [superlayer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:[superlayer.sublayers count]];
}

- (void)sendSublayerToBack:(CALayer *)layer {
    CALayer *superlayer = layer.superlayer;
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [superlayer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a category of CALayer like this:

```
@interface CALayer (Utils)

- (void)bringSublayerToFront;

@end

@implementation CALayer (Utils)

- (void)bringSublayerToFront {
    CGFloat maxZPosition = 0;  // The higher the value, the closer it is to the front. By default is 0.
    for (CALayer *layer in self.superlayer.sublayers) {
        maxZPosition = (layer.zPosition > maxZPosition) ? layer.zPosition : maxZPosition;
    }
    self.zPosition = maxZPosition + 1;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct code:

```
-(void)bringSubLayerToFront:(CALayer*)layer
{
  [layer.superLayer addSubLayer:layer];
}

-(void)sendSubLayerToBack:(CALayer*)layer
{
  [layer.superlayer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this functionality in a category on **CALayer** like so:

**CALayer+Extension.h**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

typedef void (^ActionsBlock)(void);

@interface CALayer (Extension)

+ (void)performWithoutAnimation:(ActionsBlock)actionsWithoutAnimation;
- (void)bringSublayerToFront:(CALayer *)layer;

@end
```

**CALayer+Extension.m**

```
#import "CALayer+Extension.h"

@implementation CALayer (Extension)

+ (void)performWithoutAnimation:(ActionsBlock)actionsWithoutAnimation
{
    if (actionsWithoutAnimation)
    {
        // Wrap actions in a transaction block to avoid implicit animations.
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

        actionsWithoutAnimation();

        [CATransaction commit];
    }
}

- (void)bringSublayerToFront:(CALayer *)layer
{
    // Bring to front only if already in this layer's hierarchy.
    if ([layer superlayer] == self)
    {
        [CALayer performWithoutAnimation:^{

            // Add 'layer' to the end of the receiver's sublayers array.
            // If 'layer' already has a superlayer, it will be removed before being added.
            [self addSublayer:layer];
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

And for easy access you can `#import "CALayer+Extension.h"` in your project's **Prefix.pch** (precompiled header) file.